# devise ruby 2.3.1 rails 5.1.1 recuperar contraseña

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola estoy instalando devise y cuando lo voy a restaurar la contraseña me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pongo el correo y arreglo este proplema.

**Gemfile**

```
  gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
  gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
  gem 'devise-i18n'
  gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.15'
  gem 'mail'
```

**reset_password_instructions.html.erb**

```
  <p><%= link_to t('.action', default: 'Change my password'), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token, locale: I18n.locale) %></p>
```

No se como hacerlo.

Comment: No tienes seteado la configuración del host para correos en devise, quizá te pueda ayudar esta información https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-:host-and-:port-for-all-devise-mailer-urls

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas cambiar tu archivo config/environments/development.rb y agregar

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Si en produccion quieres agregar un host cambia el archivo config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'CHANGETHIS' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```